# How to attach a database using sp_attach_db in vc++ application using ADO

Tags: sql, visual-c++, ado

I need to install SQL server using ADO in VC++ application, fortunately it is done.
Then I need to attach a precreated Database using ADO to the instence of the installed SQL server 2005 Express using ADO through my VC++ application.How do I go about this? Can any one please help me with the code!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the database file(s) on the to server running your SQL Server instance.

As far as I know, you can't do that through ADO.  You may need to copy it over a network, through FTP, or some equivilent non-sql mechanism.

Comment: Hi Dems...thanks for responding. I have moved the .mdf and .ldf files by this code:- MoveFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\vijayalakshmi\\Desktop\\ferozkhan\\ECGManagementSystem.mdf",L"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\ECGManagementSystem.mdf");
   MoveFile(L"C:\\Documents and Settings\\vijayalakshmi\\Desktop\\ferozkhan\\ECGManagementSystem_log.ldf",L"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL.1\\MSSQL\\Data\\ECGManagementSystem_log.ldf");

Comment: I also connected to the master database by this code:-                                                                          hr= theApp.m_pConnection.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Connection));
  _bstr_t strCon("Provider = sqloledb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID="";Password="";Initial Catalog=master;Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
  if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
  {
   hr = theApp.m_pConnection->Open(strCon,_bstr_t(L""),_bstr_t(L""),0);
   AfxMessageBox(L"Connected to the master database",0,0);
  }

Comment: After this I will have to attach to the database i.e.. ECGManagementSystem(.mdf,.ldf)...for this I have tryied this:-                                                                          theApp.m_pCom.CreateInstance(_uuidof(Command));
   theApp.m_pCom->ActiveConnection = theApp.m_pConnection;                                                           theApp.m_pCom->CommandType = adCmdStoredProc;

Comment: csTemp.Format(L"exec sp_attach_db @dbname = ECGManagementSystem;@filename1 = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\ECGManagementSystem.mdf;@filename2 = C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Data\ECGManagementSystem_log.ldf");

Comment: theApp.m_pCom->CommandText = _bstr_t("sp_attach_db");                                                 hr = theApp.m_pCom->Execute(NULL,NULL,adCmdStoredProc); 
   if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    AfxMessageBox(L"Database attached",0,0);
   else
                AfxMessageBox(L"Database NOT attached",0,0);
   return true;                                                                        But the attaching by sp_attach_db does not work...What do I do now?